# Auto mapper 9 List mapping not working asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have updated the Automapper to 9.0 and the earlier code is broken. I was using

```
 <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.2.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="3.2.0" />
```

I am trying to map the List as per this code

```
 public class ProjectBudgetSummaryProfile : Profile
    {
        public ProjectBudgetSummaryProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel, HdsBudgetSummary>();
            CreateMap<ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel, CdsBudgetSummary>();
        }
    }

var finance = _mapper.Map<List<ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel>>(budgetSummaries)


 public class ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel
    {
        public decimal? CurrentApproval { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentForecast { get; set; }
        public decimal? Delta { get; set; }
        public string FinancialItemDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal? ForecastDelta { get; set; }
        public decimal? PreviousForecast { get; set; }
        public long? ForecastId { get; set; }
    }

public class HdsBudgetSummary : BudgetSummary
    {
    }

 public class BudgetSummary
    {
        public decimal? CurrentApproval { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentForecast { get; set; }
        public decimal? Delta { get; set; }
        public string FinancialItemDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal? ForecastDelta { get; set; }
        public decimal? PreviousForecast { get; set; }
        public int ProjectNumber { get; set; }
        public long? ForecastId { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration setup

```
 public virtual IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ConfigureMapping(services);
            return ServiceProvider;
        }


protected virtual void ConfigureMapping(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(assembly => !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceDataCollector")));
        }
```

Error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
HdsBudgetSummary -> ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel
ProjectPerformanceReview.DomainModel.ComplexDomainModel.Hds.HdsBudgetSummary -> ProjectPerformanceReview.WebApi.ViewModels.BudgetSummary.ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel
```

Some of the links I followed 
[Mapping Lists using Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper)

[Automapper 8 mapping not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611638/automapper-8-mapping-not-working-properly)

Comment: But isn't the error message already telling you what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your profile is only mapping from `ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel` to `HdsBudgetSummary`. If you want it to map in the opposite direction as well, you have to extend the profile.

```cs
public ProjectBudgetSummaryProfile()
{
   CreateMap<ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel, HdsBudgetSummary>()
      ReverseMap();
   CreateMap<ProjectBudgetSummaryViewModel, CdsBudgetSummary>()
      ReverseMap();
}
```

FYI: You don't need to return `IServiceProvider` from the `ConfigureServices` delegate.